# Display order attributes in back-end

Tags: attributes, orders, payment, backend

I have added 2 new input fields in one of my payment methods in the template. Here's the code:

```
<input type="text" id="swiftcode" name="payment[debit_swift]" title="<?php echo $this->__('SWIFT Code') ?>" class="input-text" value="<?php echo $this->getAccountSwift() ?>" />
```

and

```
<input type="text" id="iban" name="payment[debit_iban]" title="<?php echo $this->__('IBAN') ?>" class="input-text" value="<?php echo $this->getAccountIban() ?>" />
```

I in the DB table `sales_flat_order_payment` the column name for the 2 attributes is `debit_swift` and `debit_iban`.

So, so when I tried to show the information in the order details in the back-end, I couldn't. I have added the text, but I do not get the information that has been saved in the order:

```
<?php echo $this->__('BIC (Swift-code): ', $this->htmlEscape($_info->getAccountSwift())) ?><br />
<?php echo $this->__('IBAN: ', $this->htmlEscape($_info->getAccountIban())) ?><br />
```

I use `$_info->getAccount...()` because for the other attributes (that are input fields in the front-end and are shown in the order details in the back-end) is used the same way of acquiring the information.

Any suggestions on that how to show the information in the back-end order details?

EDIT: this is the whole code of the template.

```
<?php if ($_info = $this->getMethod()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_info->getTitle()) ?><br /><br />

    <?php if ($this->isEmailContext()): ?>

        <?php if ($this->sendDataInEmail()): ?>
            <?php $_data = $this->getEmailData() ?>
            <?php if (!empty($_data['bank_name'])): ?>
                <?php echo $this->__('Bank name: %s', $this->htmlEscape($_data['bank_name'])) ?><br />
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php echo $this->__('Bank code: %s', $this->htmlEscape($_data['account_blz'])) ?><br />
            <?php echo $this->__('Account holder: %s', $this->htmlEscape($_data['account_name'])) ?><br />
            <?php echo $this->__('Account number: %s', $this->htmlEscape($_data['account_number'])) ?><br />
            <?php echo $this->__('BIC (Swift-code): ', $this->htmlEscape($_data['swift'])) ?><br />
            <?php echo $this->__('IBAN: ', $this->htmlEscape($_data['iban'])) ?><br />
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php else: ?>

        <?php if ($_info->getAccountBankname() == Mage::helper('debit')->__('not available')): ?>
            <span style="color: #cc0000;font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $this->__('Fehler! Die eingegebenen Bankdaten können fehlerhaft sein!<br />Bitte setzen Sie sich mit dem Kunden in Verbindung!') ?></span><br /><br />
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->__('Bank name: %s', $this->htmlEscape($_info->getAccountBankname())) ?><br />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $this->__('Account holder: %s', $this->htmlEscape($_info->getAccountName())) ?><br />
        <?php echo $this->__('Account number: %s', $this->htmlEscape($_info->getAccountNumber())) ?><br />
        <?php echo $this->__('Bank code: %s', $this->htmlEscape($_info->getAccountBLZ())) ?><br />
        <?php echo $this->__('Customer number: %s', $this->htmlEscape($_info->getInfoInstance()->getKundennummer())) ?><br />
        <?php echo $this->__('BIC (Swift-code): ', $this->htmlEscape($_info->getAccountSwift())) ?><br />
        <?php echo $this->__('IBAN: ', $this->htmlEscape($_info->getAccountIban())) ?><br />

        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <br />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: the problem was in the `$this->__(...)` and `$this->htmlEscape(...)` functions. Now the working code for these 2 lines looks like that:

```
<?php echo 'BIC (Swift-code): '.$_info->getAccountSwift() ?><br />
<?php echo 'IBAN: '.$_info->getAccountIban() ?><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you closely look your code it should be as follows.

```
<?php echo $this->__('BIC (Swift-code): ', $this->htmlEscape($_info->getAccountSwift())) ?><br />
<?php echo $this->__('IBAN: ', $this->htmlEscape($_info->getAccountIban())) ?><br />
```

Comment: Okay, I see that I have missed the `t` on `getAccountIban()`. But I still do not get any information displayed. Is there anything in `Configuration` tab that has to be set?

Comment: Did you try to var_dump() the order object and check whether it contains the info which you are looking for?

Comment: I am not using the order object in the template. I updated my question with the whole code from the template.

Comment: In the template file log the array contents of $_data and $_info. Check the logged data